# Как дать определенному пользователю Debian права на запуск определенного Docker-контейнера в sudo

Tags: linux, docker, debian, sudo

Необходимо предоставить определенному пользователю Debian права на запуск определенного Docker-контейнера в sudo.
Задаю в visudo команду для запуска, но он начинает ругаться на конец строки. Что я делаю не так?

```
/etc/sudoers:24:112: ошибка синтаксиса
%my_container ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/docker run --rm -ti my_container:v03mb
                                                                                 ^
What now?
```

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file тут есть про запуск с параметрами `GROUPTWO ALL = /usr/bin/apt-get update`, но я пока не разобрался как к тебе это применить.

Comment: `Cmnd_Alias EXECUTE_DOCKER = /usr/bin/docker run --rm -ti my_container` - пашет. Судоерсу не нравится конкретно `:`. Можешь сделать, чтобы `v03mb` на самом деле был `latest`?

Comment: А, заэкранировать надо. `my_container\:v03mb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Валидатор `visudo` ругается на двоеточие. Надо просто заэкранировать.

```
%my_container ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/docker run --rm -ti my_container\:v03mb
```

Comment: Добрый день. Простите за ожидание, только смог проверить - действительно экранирование работает.